# Which were the latest 13 consecutive years with the most friday 13. in total?

Tags: code-golf, date

Shortest program wins, of course.

Comment: You may want to try "The Sandbox" for future challenges. Also, include the challenge in the body, with a very short title. Are we supposed to take the current time as input or get it via a date function? Are the consecutive thirteen years within 0-the current year? Can the current year be included in the 13 consecutive years? What should our program return if there is a tie between two different thirteen consecutive years?

Comment: And what stops submissions from just hardcoding it?

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether it actually needs to depend on the date it's run on or if it's actually meant to be [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]... which is a difficult question to resolve (along with output format and just about everything else) when the body is shorter than the title.

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram Language 171 bytes

Any modern 13-year interval will have between 20 and 24 Friday the 13ths.

```
SortBy[{{#[[1,1]],#[[-1,1]]},Total[#[[2]]&/@#]}&/@Partition[Table[{y,Length@Cases[DateObject@{y,m,13}~Table~{m,12},x_/;DayName@x==Friday]},{y,1900,2019}],13,1],Last][[-1]]

* {{2007, 2019}, 24} *)
```

The above generates all the Friday the 13ths for each year between 1900 and 2019, partitions the results into intervals of 13 years, and finds the total for each such interval.  The interval of 2007-2019 has 24, the maximum number of Friday the 13ths.

If 2019 cannot be used, the correct answer will be the interval of 200-2018, which also contains 24 Friday the 13ths.